# Controller in subfolder cant be loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

Morning all,

Im having very troubles with controllers/uri and subfolders, the directory looks like this:

```
application/
     controllers/
         d2/
         mc/
             cp/
             --- login.php
     ...
```

The `routes.php` is :

```
$route["cp"] = "mc/cp/login/login_form";
$route["cp/login"] = "mc/cp/login/login_form";
```

And the `login.php` is :

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function login_form() {
        echo "hey!";
    }
}
```

On the logs file, i can see this:

```
ERROR - 10/03/2013, 09:45:00 --> 404 Page Not Found --> mc/cp
```

But, when i try to enter in `http://localhost/mc/cp` or `http://localhost/mc/cp/login` returns a 404 error, where exactly is the problem? that after moving the controller to the `controllers/mc` folder the file load without problems..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a workaround I found in an of a link in another post, although I haven't tried it.

http://glennpratama.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/multi-level-subfolder-for-controller-in-codeigniter/

just for info, you are allowed sub-sub directories in most other locations, in particular `views`,`models` and `helpers`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Reading the [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#subfolders) carefully, i found that i had not read well how to handle subdirectories of controllers:

> Simply create folders within your application/controllers directory and place your controller classes within them.

It can not be a subdirectory of a directory, but a directory directly, like this:

```
application/
    controllers/
        d2/
        mc/
        cp/
        --- login.php
    ...
```